# How to add a conditional to the last element of a loop

Tags: javascript

I understand the problem I have facing, but I don't know how to go about fixing it. I have 6 input fields whereby, whenever you enter a value in one input field, it goes to the next and then activates the .focus() method.

The issue here is that, after the last input field, there is no more input field which then leads to the error, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')".

I have tried adding several else if's statement to disable the focus after the last input field has been entered but seems its not working and I keep getting the error.

index.html

```
<div class="code-container">
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
</div>
```

script.js

```
const codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code");

codes[0].focus();

codes.forEach((code, idx) => {
  code.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    console.log(idx);
    if (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
      codes[idx].value = "";
      setTimeout(() => codes[idx + 1].focus(), 10);
    } else if (e.key === "Backspace") {
      setTimeout(() => codes[idx - 1].focus(), 10);
    } else if (idx == codes.length - 1) {
      codes[idx].blur();
    }
  });
});
```

error log

```
script.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you definitely should compare the codes.length and compare it with idx to apply the move to the next element except the last one as below

```js
    const codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code");
    codes[0].focus();
    const codexLastIndex = codes.length - 1;

    codes.forEach((code, idx) => {
      code.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        console.log(idx);
        const isLastElement = e.target == codes[codes.length - 1];
        const isFirstElement = e.target == codes[0];

        // special use case for the last element 
        if (isLastElement) {
         if ( e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
          codes[idx].value = e.key;
         } 
        }
        if ( ( e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) && !isLastElement) {
          codes[idx].value = "";
          setTimeout(() => codes[idx + 1].focus(), 10);

        } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && !isFirstElement) { // remove the error with the backspace in the first element
          setTimeout(() => codes[idx - 1].focus(), 10);
        } else if (idx == codes.length - 1) {
          codes[idx].blur();
        }
      });
    });
```

this code uses `e.preventDefault();` for logic wise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```js
 const codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code");
    codes[0].focus();
    const codexLastIndex = codes.length - 1;

    codes.forEach((code, idx) => {

      code.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // here adding preventDefault() function to stop the defaults actions 
        const isLastElement = e.target == codes[codes.length - 1];
        const isFirstElement = e.target == codes[0];

        // special use case for the last element 
        if (isLastElement) {
         if ( e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
          codes[idx].value = e.key;
         } 
        }
        if ( ( e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) && !isLastElement) {
          codes[idx].value = e.key;
          setTimeout(()=> codes[idx + 1].focus(), 10);

        } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && !isFirstElement) { // remove the error with the backspace in the first element
          setTimeout(() => codes[idx - 1].focus(), 10);
        } else if (idx == codes.length - 1) {
          codes[idx].blur();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It works pretty fine just that when I reach the last input field, it accepts two values, that is a tens unit whereas I have placed a max of 9 in the html property. How can I fix that?

Comment: I have edited the code please check it out, it should work perfectly now

Comment: Thank you very much. Please can you explain this line of code, `codes[idx].value = "";`. I feel it means that each input field value should be null/nothing but it doesn't work that way. Also, I noticed with the code in place, it helps to prevent multiple values in the field but I just don't get the logic.

Comment: @oyerohabib `codes[idx].value = "";` applies to the one you focus on next so in this case it will apply to the next element as  `codes[idx + 1].value = "";` if you don't focus on any other element, the input will be duplicated in the same element, if you type `6` the input will be `66` and this is a default behavior that happens and you can stop it by using `event.preventDefault();` I have added the code using `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

That is probably a job for the [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator.

Replace `idx + 1` by `(idx + 1) % codes.length`.

Here is your code changed a little...
To take in account the `blur` expected for the last input... And to avoid an error on `backspace` on the first one.

```js
const codes = document.querySelectorAll(".code");

codes[0].focus();

codes.forEach((code, idx) => {
  code.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    console.log(idx);
    
    if (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
      if (idx == codes.length - 1) {
       setTimeout(() => codes[idx].blur(), 10);
        return
      }
      codes[idx].value = "";
      setTimeout(() => codes[(idx + 1) % codes.length].focus(), 10);
    } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && idx != 0) {
      setTimeout(() => codes[(idx - 1) % codes.length].focus(), 10);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="code-container">
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
  <input type="number" class="code" placeholder="0" min="0" max="9" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That works in a way. how about disabling the focus when after value for the last digit as been entered. I know the .blur() can be used to achieve that, but I don't know how to place the conditional for that.

Comment: Thank you. This now works in a way. After the last input field value has been entered the focus leaves which is good but the value remains empty.

Comment: Yes... It also needs a setTimeout. I edited.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It now works even better but I notice that for the backspace, when you focus the mouse on the last input field and hit the backspace key to delete the elements, after the deleting the last element, it removes the focus and then your need to focus the mouse manually to keep deleting the inputs.

Comment: Ok... Then just moving the blur condition fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `codes[idx].blur();` to `e.preventDefault`
You can also see here for more details [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339343/cycle-focus-to-first-form-element-from-last-element-vice-versa?rq=1)